# Nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

I have 3 models in my application: Resource, Company, Manager.

```
Resource has_many :managers
Resource has_many :companies
Company has_many :managers
Manager belongs_to :company
Manager belongs_to :resource
```

How can I include nested attributes for companies and resources in the edit view for Manager?

Answer (score 0):

Check out Ryan Bates' Railscasts on Nested Model Forms: [Part 1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) and [Part 2](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2)